# How to put in the thousands separator in xlsx using xlsxwriter module?

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

When using xlsxwriter how do you get the xlsx file to contain columns with comma formatted numbers(not strings) in a column?

**What I want to do -** turn 1000 into 1,000 while preserving value as a number

Failed attempts...

```
#gives warning in cell (asking if it should be a number) + writes as string not number
sheet.write_string(0,0,re.sub("^0*|\.?0*$","",format(val, ',.10f')) )

# writes as number with no warning, but no commas
sheet.write_number(0,0,1000)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to set the cell's [format](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/working_with_formats.html) to specify how the number should be represented:

```
num_fmt = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,###'})
...
sheet.write_number(0, 0, 1000, num_fmt)
```

Comment: Just an observation: `'#,###'` will show an empty cell if the value is zero; you can use `'#,##0'` to show the zeros.

Comment: Also worth mentioning, if you are getting an error saying that "int type is not callable" or something similar, make sure you are using `format.set_num_format()` instead of `format.num_format()`

Comment: The link is broken. Maybe https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html ?